Parameters of Wishart distribution and generalized inverse
I recently came across the Wishart Distribution and a few things are unclear to me.

The Wikipedia page for the Wishart Distribution says that if $G=[g_1 \vert \; g_2\vert \; \ldots \vert g_n]$ is a $p \times n$ matrix such that $g_i \sim N_p(0,V)$ are i.i.d copies, then $S=GG^T$ is said to have the $p$-dimensional Wishart Distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom and parameter $V$.
My question is about the statement: If $n≥p$ and $V$ is invertible, then $S$ is invertible almost surely. How does one prove this and why does one need the $n≥p$ condition?
If $S$ as defined above is invertible, $S^{-1}$ is said to have the $p$-dimensional inverse Wishart Distribution with degrees of freedom n and parameter $V^{-1}$, denoted by $W_p^{-1}(V^{-1},n).$ If $S$ is not invertible, can any comment be made about the generalized inverses of $S$?

I apologize if these questions are fairly simple in the literature, but any help is appreciated!

The rank of $GG^T$ cannot be more than the rank of $G$, and that cannot be more than $n,$ so if $n<p,$ then $V$ cannot be invertible.
As for the converse, notice that $S$ not being invertible would mean that some column of $S$ is a linear combination of the others. The question then becomes: Why is the probability of that equal to $0$? Notice that this means: when that component of a column of $S$ that is orthogonal to the other columns of $S$ has positive variance, then why is it almost surely nonzero?
